# Getting Leaflet and image popup from QGIS export working?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2leaf

I am a novice in using leaflet, I exported my map layers from QGIS to a working Leaflet map. I am trying to modify the popup to use the attribute so as to get an image popup. i am however stuck as i have read documentation but still unsure. Any leads will help. Currently my popup does a get feature info to show the following.

```
function pop_dwelling(feature, layer) {
                                        var popupContent = '<table><tr><th  scope="row">house_numb</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties.house_numb)) + '</td></tr><tr><th  scope="row">photo</th><td>' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties.photo)) + '</td></tr><tr><th </td></tr></table>';
                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);


                }
```

where the photo is a column in the vector that has the path to the image

Comment: Do you use qgis2leaf? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2leaf/

Comment: Can somebody explain how to do that in "for dummies" mode?
I have attribute field "photo" with names like "images001", "images002", etc., as "text edit" widget.
I copied all pictures to "pictures" folder, and edited index.html with '<img src=\"pictures/' + feature.properties.photo + '\" />' but pictures dont show up? Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Does your column 'photo' contain just a filename? If so, this is what you'd have to do:

1. Copy all the images to a subfolder in your qgis2leaf output folder (I think there's one there already for images, but can't remember what it's called)
2. Change the popup code for the photo column from:

   Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties.photo))

to

```
'<img src="subfoldername/' + feature.properties.photo + '" />'
```

See if that does the trick.

Comment: yes i used qgis2leaf and there is a folder for pictures called pictures. the column photo contains a filename only.

Comment: OK, so: `'<img src="pictures/' + feature.properties.photo + '" />'` (**NOTE** I missed out the required opening " in my answer).

Comment: what do you mean the required opening? is it the '<table><tr><th  scope="row">house_numb</th><td>' part

Comment: you are concatenating strings and variables with javascript to create html that gets passed to the feature's pop-up in leaflet. You should read up on this to understand what's going on. See this post: http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp

Comment: p.s. the code @TomChadwin mentioned will throw an error. Change it to: '<img src=\"pictures/' + feature.properties.photo + '\" />'